# How to read a JSON for just one time and use it many time in the same robot file in Robot Framework

Tags: json, selenium, testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I am implementing a test automation framework with using robot framework. But i couldn't manage some JSON things.. I have a robot file full of keywords (no tests), i tried to read the json file (with full of xpaths) in test setup section, but it failed.

Is it possible to read the file at the beginning of a robot file and use that object for every keyword in that list?

Current structure:

```
keyword 1
  read json
  do sth

keyword 2
  read json
  do sth

keyword 3
  read json
  do sth
```

What i want?

```
read json

keyword 1
  do sth
keyword 2
  do sth
keyword 3
  do sth
```

Current İmplemantation:

```
*** Settings ***
    Library   SeleniumLibrary
    Library   JSONLibrary
    Library   OperatingSystem
    Resource  ../PageObjects/LoginPage.robot


Suite Setup  Read object repository locators
*** Keywords ***

Read object repository locators
        [Documentation]  For all elements on website, this keyword is returns an 
        xpath collection for other keywords
        # read the json data
        ${json}=  Get file  ../library/ObjectRepository.json
        # convert the data to a object
        ${object}=  Evaluate  json.loads(r'''${json}''')
        set suite variable  ${object}

Read object
       ${password}=  Set Variable  ${object["registerInfo"][0]["password"]}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me when I fix the errors and add a test that calls `Read Object`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to read the file at the beginning of a robot file and use that object for every keyword in that list?

Yes. You can read the data in and then use [Set suite variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) to create a variable that is available everywhere in the suite.

The following example defines a keyword you can run in a suite setup. It will read in a json file (stored in the robot variable `${data_file}`) and save the data to a suite variable named `${data}`. You can then use `${data}` in any test in the suite.

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup    Load JSON data

*** Keywords***
Load JSON data
    ${data}=     evaluate  json.load(open($data_file, 'r'))
    set suite variable  ${data}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your comment. I already tried it but didn't work.It says 'Variable ${object} not found' I'm editing the question with my existing code

Comment: @mert: the code in your question doesn't give me that error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Suite Setup` keyword to set suite level variable or you can use variable files by creating custom Python script which reads JSON file and returns it.

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    read_json.py
```